# How to show xAxis label in tooltip in a Highcharts area chart?

Tags: highcharts

I am using xAxis labels (not categories) to remove left/right paddings.

```
    xAxis: {
        //categories: data.categories
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return cat[this.value];
            }
        },
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0
    },
```

In the tooltip, `{point.x}` shows me the number (eg. "0"), but I want the label (eg. "Jan").

```
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
            pointFormat: "{series.name}: {point.y:.0f} ({point.percentage:.1f}%)<br />",
            headerFormat: "<b>{point.x}</b><br><br>",
    },
```

How can I make it show the label?

http://jsfiddle.net/9tgjf82e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to associate points with their names, so you need points in the format `[name, y]`

Then you can access point's name via `point.key` in the headerFormat.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/9tgjf82e/4/

Comment: That's a lot more complicated than I thought (I was hoping it would be like `{point.xLabel}`, thank you! :)

Comment: You could also find hurricane's answer to be useful. It needs a little adjustment to fix the tick placement so there is no padding on the left/right. http://jsfiddle.net/9tgjf82e/5/ plotOptions.series.pointPlacement: 'on'

Comment: morganfree you are the best!! Now that is the answer! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `point.key` in header format.

[API Doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.headerFormat)

> The point.key variable contains the category name, x value or datetime
>   string depending on the type of axis. For datetime axes, the point.key
>   date format can be set using tooltip.xDateFormat.

But you need to define your xAxis->categories.

```
xAxis: {
    categories : cat,
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return cat[this.value];
         }
    }
},


tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true,
    pointFormat: "{series.name}: {point.y:.0f} ({point.percentage:.1f}%)<br />",
    headerFormat: "<b>{point.key}</b><br><br>",
},
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tgjf82e/1/)

Comment: Thanks but as stated on my first sentence, we cannot use categories because we cannot have any left/right paddings (ie. the chart must be stretched to full width).